# Add significance stars in gtsummary on an anova

Tags: r, statistics, anova, gtsummary

Is it possible to add significance stars on a gtsummary rendered table, with an anova ?
I saw that it is possible with a regression, but I can't find any info on an anova. I'm trying to have stars appear next to the p values (the values on the table are non-sense but it's normal).

[image: table]

Here is my code :

```r
library(gtsummary)

tbl_summary(data, by = Groupe, statistic = list(all_continuous()~ "{mean} ({sd})")) %>%
  add_p(test = everything() ~ "aov", pvalue_fun = ~ style_pvalue(.x, digits = 2))
```

Comment: I thought `add_significance_stars()` would work on this table, but it looks like it is only compatible with `tbl_regression()` and `tbl_uvregression()` objects. I _think_ it should not be too much work to expand support for `tbl_summary()` objects. Please file an issue on the gtsummary GitHub page to request support.